# Differences between EPROM and EEPROM

Tags: mosfet, eeprom, rom, common-gate

I found one valuable [Utmel blog](https://www.utmel.com/blog/categories/memory%20chip/introduction-to-eprom-and-eeprom) which explains the three things:

> The internal chip can be erased by irradiating ultraviolet rays through the hole. The **EPROM eraser** is needed to complete the chip erasing operation.
>
> PROM is a programmable device. The mainstream product adopts a **double-layer gate** (two-layer poly) structure, **including EPROM and EEPROM**.

And EEPROM and EPROM internal structure **seems to be same** because they both use the **double-layer gate**:

eliminate the electron in EEPROM
[image]

---

I also found another [Naver blog](https://blog.naver.com/beahey/220375952430) which compares EPROM and EEPROM although I don't master the Korean language:

[image]
[image]

From the 3rd figure, the EPROM has no circuit to induce electrons while the EEPROM has by using `WL,BL` to control the electron induction in the double-layer gate. This shows how [NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NOR_flash) flash (one type of the EEPROM) works.

---

Q1: EPROM and EEPROM are **only different** that they use different erasing technology but the internal structure are same.

Are the statements right?

P.S. Answer to the old 2nd question in the [history](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/675556/timeline#history_33c48984-93b8-4075-ac15-0cfb0a06c1f6): [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Floating-gate_MOSFET) EEPROM by using one "intermediate voltage" is similar to how DRAM is read

Comment: That's a bit like saying cars and motorbikes only differ in the number of wheels they have. There are a great many varieties of both.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understanded after reading your analogy.

Comment: The diagram you linked shows a different structure, at least quantitatively. 100Å vs 250Å is a significant difference. BTW, there are/were also "EPROM" chips which were the same UVEPROM chip but packaged in a plastic (opaque) package, which obviously cannot be erased by UV light. This is still a commonly available program memory type in very low-end MCU chips such as [this](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810301810_PADAUK-Tech-PMS150C-S08_C129127.pdf) one (less than 2.5 cents USD), where it is called OTP = One Time Programmable.

Comment: Yes, the current is one difference and also there are small differences inside the UVEPROM as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV EPROMs were available many years before EEPROMs were developed.  I think EEPROMs have replaced UVPROMs now. Digikey does list some UVPROMs that I remember, but shows them all as "obsolete - no stock".

Comment: Yes, maybe I focus too much on the details of something obsolete. I think your answer is better if equipped with the above comment by you.

Answer (score 1):

EPROM is erased with UV light, making it less flexible and slower, while EEPROM can be electrically erased and rewritten, offering greater speed, versatility, and endurance, making it more suitable for modern electronic applications.

Comment: Your answer is general, also useful in some way. Thanks.