# Does "field electron emission" used in EEPROM work better than "hot-carrier injection" in NOR Flash?

Tags: mosfet, design, memory, flash, eeprom

After deeping research based on my another [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/675556), I continued comparing Flash and EEPROM based on wikipedia [comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM#Comparison_with_EPROM_and_EEPROM/flash).

From [wikipedia about the Flash memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Programming):

> Programming
>
> the **source-drain current** is sufficiently high to cause some high energy electrons to jump through the insulating layer onto the FG, via a process called **hot-electron injection**.
>
> Erasing
>
> To erase a NOR flash cell (resetting it to the "1" state), a large voltage of the opposite polarity is applied **between the CG and source terminal**, pulling the electrons off the FG through quantum tunneling.

---

This figure referenced from [Utmel blog](https://www.utmel.com/blog/categories/memory%20chip/introduction-to-eprom-and-eeprom) shows how EEPROM uses "field electron emission":
[image]

---

Also from wikipedia about [NAND Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Writing_and_erasing), its writing and elimination work same as EEPROM maybe because:

> several transistors are connected in **series**

So using current to drive may be **expensive**.

Q: Then can EEPROM also use "hot-carrier injection" when writing by theory just as how Flash does?

Does "field electron emission" show better performance than "hot-carrier injection" so that EEPROM uses the former?